# Fazer click da div abrir option

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma div *selectClick*, e gostaria que quando eu clicasse nela, abrisse um option que está abaixo. 
Da forma que estou fazendo não está funcionando.

```js
$('li div.selectClick').click(function() {
  $(".div-select select").slideDown('slow');
})
```

```css
.div-select { width:215px; display: none; }
.div-select select {
    background: /*url(/assets/images/arrow-down.png)*/ no-repeat #1b4b93;
    background-position: 205px center;
    width: 215px;
    height: 60px;
    font: 200 10px/10px 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:13px 20px 13px 12px;
    color:#fff;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
    select::-ms-expand {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="selectClick">Ver todas linhas</div>
  <div class="div-select">
    <select>
    <option>Ver todas as linhas</option>
    <option>Primeira opção</option>
    <option>Segunda opção</option>
    <option>Terceira opção</option>
    <option>Quarta opção</option>
   </select>https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/237641/edit#
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Você tá querendo mostrar as opções do select quando clicar na div? é isso?

Comment: @JuniorNunes isso mesmo

Comment: Acredito que isso não seja possível, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430241/6101515)

Comment: @JuniorNunes queria que quando eu clicasse na div ele mostrasse os options.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é pegar as options do select e mostrar elas de alguma forma, agora mostrar as opções dentro do select "não é possível"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente isso não é possível, mas como tudo na vida, da pra fazer de algum jeito,  da uma olhada no trecho a baixo, acredito que deva ter algum outro meio, mas esse foi o unico que consegui pensar:

```js
$(document).on('click','.selectClick',function(){
   var $sel = $('select');
   $sel.show();
   $sel[0].size=5;
});

$(document).on('click','.select',function(){
   var $sel = $(this);
   $sel[0].size=1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <div class="selectClick">Ver todas linhas</div>
  <div class="div-select">
    <select class='select'>
    <option>Ver todas as linhas</option>
    <option>Primeira opção</option>
    <option>Segunda opção</option>
    <option>Terceira opção</option>
    <option>Quarta opção</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alterar seu JS para este:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectClick',function(event) {
$('.select').slideDown('slow');    
});​
```

Comment: Não deu certo assim.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isso que você quer:

```js
$('li div.selectClick').click(function() {
  $(".div-select").slideDown('slow');
})
```

```css
.div-select { width:215px; display: none; }
.div-select select {
    background: /*url(/assets/images/arrow-down.png)*/ no-repeat #1b4b93;
    background-position: 205px center;
    width: 215px;
    height: 60px;
    font: 200 10px/10px 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:13px 20px 13px 12px;
    color:#fff;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: "";
    select::-ms-expand {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <div class="selectClick">Ver todas linhas</div>
  <div class="div-select">
    <select>
    <option>Ver todas as linhas</option>
    <option>Primeira opção</option>
    <option>Segunda opção</option>
    <option>Terceira opção</option>
    <option>Quarta opção</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, como o pessoal disse, não é possível somente com o jQuery...
Recomendo você a utilizar alguma biblioteca para isso, por exemplo o Select2 (https://select2.org/), dessa maneira fica fácil:

Adicione o css:

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

E o JS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Depois seu script fica assim:

```
    $('#mySelect').select2();
    $('li div.selectClick').click(function() {
        $('#mySelect').select2('open');
    });
```

Só não esqueça de por um ID pro seu select, ali no caso coloquei "mySelect"